The difference between "limit"(n.) and "limitation"
Could you tell me the difference between "limit"(n.) and "limitation"?

For questions about what words mean, please look them up in a dictionary and then edit the question to tell about what you found and what questions remain. This will make the answers more useful to you so that answerers can help fill in any gaps that aren't clear from the dictionary.

A "limit" is measurable, semi-measurable, or a discrete barrier or ceiling.  Examples:  "Speed Limit","Credit limit", "You are limited to 1000 queries by your subscription","The machine ran up against a hard limit","All velocities are limited by the speed of light."
Limitation is more general and abstract, and usually refers to a property whose value is insufficient for a task or other measure. "He had physical limitations which affected his work." "A limitation of stainless steel is its relatively poor thermal conductivity."  "His limitations in English made it difficult for him to handle customers." "Her culture made it difficult for her to be direct with people.  This was a limitation."

Effect and cause. A limitation is a situation that creates a limit.
Not much of a rule, but a decoration has an effect on the decor etc
